# Storing XML attribute value into a variable by using XSLT

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, attributes, storage

I am new in XSLT, and am learning how to store attribute into a variable.

I have a scenario where my input xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book title="ABC" id="1">
         <infos>
            <info key="pages">200</info>
            <info key="price">$1.50</info>
         </infos>
    </book>
    <book title="XYZ" id="1">
         <infos>
            <info key="pages">300</info>
            <info key="price">$3.00</info>
         </infos>
    </book>
</books>
```

I want to know how to store the title of a book whose pages is 200, i.e. i need the "ABC" to be stored in a variable.

I have searched many places but all I could find is how to store the last attributes value by using this code :

```
  <xsl:variable name="pages" select="/*/info[.='200']/@key"/>
```

where i can get the $key value as "pages", but i want title's value

Is is possible to get title's value by using similar approach, if yes then where am i going wrong, Thanks in Advance

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="pages" select="/*/info[.='200']/@key"/>` does not contain anything.

Comment: no it was just the code which i understood would work, have tried it properly afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to store the title of a book whose pages is 200

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="title" select="/books/book[infos/info[@key='pages']=200]/@title" />
```